# Redirect loop trying to use custom login page with next.js and nextauth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to implement custom credentials authentication in my next + nextauth project. Nextjs version is ^13.4.2 and next-auth is ^4.22.3.

- I'm able to use my pages/login.tsx, a custom signin page, if I don't use middleware.
- When I write the `pages` object to [...nextauth].ts and middleware.ts, I get redirection loop for any page that I try:
  [![chrome network console showing infinite redirections][1]][1]

What am I doing incorrectly? I'm trying to follow the docs here. Here are my conf files:

```
// src/middleware.ts
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware"

/* naturally I tried only the first object, now I'm trying to setup the signIn page 
in more places so it can be read if I'm misplacing it somehow */
export const config = {
    pages: { 
        signIn: '/login',
    },
}

export const pages = {
    signIn: '/login',
}
```

,

```
// and this is src/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
    // ...
export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

How can I debug this/ Is there some conf I'm clearly doing wrong?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfuJh.png

Comment: Thanks @kca! But Credentials is a type of provider, and jwt seems to be a way of storing the session. If defaults to jwt. Just in case I added this to my nextauth file: `session: { strategy: 'jwt' }`, but nothing seems to change. Makes stronger the argument that it was already the default behavior